# Nested For Loops for Finding Largest Value

Tags: python

I am learning how to work with nested loops. I need to find the position of the maximum value of the 'n x n' matrix, and I understand that I need to include a conditional statement that stops the nested for loops once the maximum value is confirmed. So far I managed to program a nested loop that iterates through each row and column of the matrix to output its final position.

To find the maximum of the matrix, I know a possible approach is using:

```
max(sum(matrix, []))
```

However, I am not entirely sure where to place this condition to return what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `for i in range(n)`, `i` will increase in each iteration of the loop on its own. You don't need to increment it.

Here is how you would go about traversing the matrix:

```py
n = len(matrix)
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        print('position ({}, {}) in matrix: {}'.format(i, j, n[i][j]))
```

So to find the position of the maximum value, you can keep track of the largest value you've seen so far, and the position of that value, like this:

```py
n = len(matrix)
max_value = float('-inf')
max_position = None
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        value = n[i][j]
        if value > max_value:
            max_value = value
            max_position = (i, j)
print('max value is {} at position ({}, {})'.format(
    max_value,
    max_position[0],
    max_position[1]
))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this steps:

1. Assume that the fisrt element of the matrix is the one having maximum value i.e element at [0,0] position do following, store position in two variables (e.x. **row=0**,**col=0**) and the value in **max**
2. Now, iterate through the matrix as you normally would and at every iteration check if the current element (position [i,j]) is greater than the one stored in **max**, if yes then replace the value of **max** with current element vList itemalue along with **row** and **col** and if no, then continue with next iteration.
3. Return **row** and **col**.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

print("enter the dimensions")
m = int(input())
n = int(input())

print("enter the elements of the matrix")
list1 = []

for i in range(m):
    list2 = []
    for j in range(n):
        list2.append(int(input()))
    list1.append(list2)

print(np.asarray(list1))

max_elements = []
for i in range(m):
    list1[i].sort()
    max_element = list1[i][n-1]
    max_elements.append(max_element)

max_elements.sort()
the_max_element = max_elements[m-1]

print(the_max_element)
```

I have used the concept of sorting the inner lists and then accessing the largest elements from them. Another sort is done on this new generated list to get the largest element.
Hope the above code helps you. Have used numpy to print the list in a multi-dimensional format.